# How to make Arraylist Member field safe from Race Condition in jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, singleton, race-condition, fortify

I am using Fortify tool and its pointing an issue as Race Condition: Singleton Member Field in a jsp Page. It says:
The class rateUs.jsp is a singleton, so the member field arrayList is shared between users. The result is that one user could see another user's data.

Below is the code where it is pointing as an issue.

```
 <% 
ArrayList arrayList = null
arrayList = (ArrayList) request.getSession().getAttribute("SLIST"); 
%>
```

Do I need to change something here ?

Comment: AFAIK jsps don't have any mutable state and thus them being singletons or not shouldn't matter (we'd need to see your code though). What could lead to a racing condition would be the use of a non-theadsafe list that's stored in the session: the user could issue 2 requests that write to the list in parallel thus leading to nasty bugs (we once had something similar with a `HashMap` where 2 concurrent writes led to endless loops in both threads).

Comment: I expect this is a simple test: login as two different users and verify what users can or can't see.

Answer (score -1):

Sessions are isolated and only accessible to a particular user holding a reference to the corresponding session.

However if objects from a session are stored in variables shared by others than this data could be seen (and altered) by others.

A more complete piece of the code would help.